# Cannot call function name stored in variable passed to jQuery .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a function that checks if a dynamically created element exists, and if it does, to add a hover handler. The problem is I don't know how to make the function inside the handler behave... well, as a function.

I thought I could simply use `event.data['callback']()`. I get "callback is not a function." Same happens if I use `.apply()`. I can do `eval(event.data.callback)(args)`, but I know I should avoid using `eval()` unless absolutely necessary.

```
function bindWhenElementExists(el, ev, cb, cbargs=[]) {
    if( $(el).length ) {
      $(el).on(ev, { callback: cb, args: cbargs }, function(event) {

        // These don't work
        cb([...cbargs]);
        cb.apply([...cbargs]);
        event.data['callback']([...event.data.args]);
        event.data['callback'].apply([...event.data.args]);

        // eval() works, but how can I avoid it?
        eval(event.data.callback)([...event.data.args]);

      });
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            bindWhenElementExists(el, ev, cb, cbargs);
        }, 500);
    }
}
// I'm using console.log for the third arg for debugging purposes.
bindWhenElementExists('menu-root', 'mouseenter', 'console.log', ['trigger', 'hovered main nav']);
```

I'm using jQuery for event handling 'cause, 1) it's already loaded on the site, and 2) honestly (and abashedly), it's easy and I just haven't be able to dig into event handling in vanilla JS yet.

Is there any way to save this?

Comment: You should be passing in a function, not a string. `bindWhenElementExists('menu-root', 'mouseenter', () => { console.log('trigger', 'hovered main nav'); });`

Comment: In the end you may want to look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: `$(document.body).on(event, childrenSelector, dataObject, callback)` is also an option

Comment: @epascarello That seems to have done the trick for me! Thank you. Can I accept your comment as an answer? (First time posting on SO.)
Thanks for the note about MutationObserver I'll read up on it!
@Taplar Wouldn't `$(document.body)` put the hover event on the whole page?